# Extract a numeric value of a specific length from string in R using regex

Tags: r, regex, extract, gsub, string-length

Looks like a repeat question but other answers haven't helped me. I'm trying to extract any 8 digit number in a text. The number could be anywhere in the text. It could be stand alone or follow or be followed by string. Basically, I need to extract any occurrence of 8 consecutive numerical characters from a string in R, using regex only.

This is what I attempted but to no avail:

```
> my_text <- "the number 5849 and 5555555555 shouldn't turn up. but12345654 and 99119911 should be. let's see if 1234567H also works. It shouldn't. both 12345678JE and RG10293847 should turn up as well."

> ## this doesn't work
    > gsub('(\\d{8})', '\\1', my_text)
    [1] "the number 5849 shouldn't turn up. but12345654 and 99119911 should be. let's see if 1234567H also works. It shouldn't.both 12345678JE and RG10293847 should turn up as well."
```

My desired output should extract the following numbers:

```
12345654
99119911 
12345678
10293847
```

While at it, I would also be grateful if the answer includes a second regex expression for extracting only the first occurrence of the 8-digit number:

```
12345654
```

---

EDIT: I have a very large table (about 200 million rows) for which i need to operate this on one column. what is the most efficient solution?

EDIT: I realised that there was a lack of cases in my text case. there are also some digits in the text that are more than 8 digits long, but I only want to extract the ones that are exactly 8 digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
stringr::str_extract_all(my_text, "\\d{8}")[[1]]
#[1] "12345654" "99119911" "12345678" "10293847"
```

---

Similarly, in base R we can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`

```
regmatches(my_text, gregexpr("\\d{8}", my_text))[[1]]
```

---

To get last 8 digit number, we can use

```
sub('.*(\\d{8}).*', '\\1', my_text)
#[1] "10293847"
```

whereas for first one, we can use

```
sub('.*?(\\d{8}).*', '\\1', my_text)
#[1] "12345654"
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated case where we want to match with exactly 8 digits (and not more) we can use `str_match_all` with negative look behind

```
stringr::str_match_all(my_text, "(?<!\\d)\\d{8}(?!\\d)")[[1]][, 1]
#[1] "12345654" "99119911" "12345678" "10293847"
```

Here, we get 8-digit numbers which is not followed and proceeded by a digit.

A simple option could also be to extract all the numbers from the string and keep only 8-digit numbers

```
v1 <- regmatches(my_text, gregexpr("\\d+", my_text))[[1]]
v1[nchar(v1) == 8]
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to avoid stringr? can i use sub or gsub?

Comment: I have a very large table (about 200 million rows) for which i need to operate this on one column. is there an efficient vecterised solution? or rather, what is the most efficient solution? thanks.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira I have added some options. Not sure which is the most efficient option though.

Comment: I realised that there was a lack of cases in my text case. there are also some digits in the text that are more than 8 digits long, but I only want to extract the ones that are exactly 8 digits.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira okay..I have updated the answer based on your update.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this more specifically to avoid any edge cases

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(my_text, "(?<![0-9])[0-9]{8}(?![0-9])")[[1]]
#[1] "12345654" "99119911" "12345678" "10293847"
```

---

To check the difference

```
v1 <- "hello8888882343, 888884399, 88888888, 8888888888"
str_extract_all(v1, "\\d{8}")
#[[1]]
#[1] "88888823" "88888439" "88888888" "88888888"
```

Here, it extracts the substring of consecutive numbers greater than 8.  According to the OP's post, it would have to be left

```
str_extract_all(v1,  "(?<![0-9])[0-9]{8}(?![0-9])")
#[[1]]
#[1] "88888888"
```